# ElasticSearch NEST Regexp query on multiple strings

Tags: c#, regex, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to write a query in NEST that will run the value `"*" + userInput + "*"` through the Regexp query. I basically want to find what the user input even if it's inside of a word. However, in the search bar the user can input multiple terms and I want to take each of those and match the document if any of the terms are in the document. I know using the Terms query allows you to pass in a list of strings to search but it doesn't support the wildcard characters. Is there a way to give the regexp query a list of strings or dynamically build it out?

Comment: You should use an alternation operator `|` (http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to join the term list. E.g. you have "tomato cucumber cabbage", so you must turn that into "tomato|cucumber|cabbage" to search for either term. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hmmm I guess i didn't really think to use the expression for the whole thing.